# Why does Media Storage consume so much memory and how to clear it for good?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, insufficient-memory, application-manager

Android is generaly horrible when it comes to managing or saving disk space. But recently, new problem appeared, which is the Media Storage system application which fills my internal memory (disk memory) with 350MB of data.

I deleted the data using Application manager, but the data reappears. Why does it happen and how to stop it? I saw no negative side effects of deleting Media storage data.

Comment: Memory (RAM) or storage space? Media Storage is the database of all your "media", meaning pictures, video, music, etc... The more files you have to index, the larger the storage space. Android will not work properly without this database.

Comment: I specifically mentioned disk space in the first sentence of my question. I do not even have 350 MB of media. I did not ask anyone for any media indexing.

Comment: Perhaps it is just semantics, but memory is synonymous with RAM in the US and storage is different, memory and storage are uniquely different. It is an essential service to the core of Android but your storage use is not normal... I have hundreds, maybe thousands, of pictures and songs on my device and Media Storage uses 3.41MB of storage space.  Regardless, have you just cleared the storage on the Media Storage and External Storage apps and rebooted (they are kind of linked in the OS)?

Comment: Yes, I cleared the data storage and rebooted the phone. But this is the third time I have to do this, so I came here for permanent solution.

Comment: If this has been an ongoing issue in a 4 year old device, I would suggest first that you perform a full factory reset, and if the problem continues it is likely an issue in the ROM. Due to it's age the chances of getting an update from Samsung are pretty much non-existent, so your "fix" might be to move to a custom ROM. The development community on for the SGS4 is (or was) quite robust.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I really miss the time when phones became old when they physically stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

This file apparently controls/manages what apps and files are believed to be on the phone.  Here is why I think that.
1. The galaxy Prime (don't laugh) was constantly "full" where it couldn't update anything, couldnt accept texts, etc.. on and on.
Attempting to Uninstall Facebook? done daily, only to look again and see it still installed.
Try to delete or move Pictures?  nope - "Failed to move" "Failed to delete" file.  Pics and Videos remain no matter what you do.
Final attempt? "Clear data" on the Media Storage file and Boom!!
Finally, the pictures, videos, we had tried to move or delete, and Facebook uninstall FINALLY ARE REMOVED!!

And space is back, texts are flowing, no more complaining of space etc..
I am guessing this file gets to size and point where it cannot be efficiently managed by the phone/android.